# Can't install python2 kernel for jupyter-notebook on MacOS

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to install the python2 kernel for jupyter notebook on my Macbook while following this page :

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-python-2-and-3

..but get the following error, which is rather cryptic for a (kind of) newb like me :

```
Alexandres-MBP ~ python2.7 -m ipykernel install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Users/alex/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Users/alex/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .iostream import IOPubThread
  File "/Users/alex/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/ipykernel/iostream.py", line 25, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.session import extract_header
  File "/Users/alex/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/jupyter_client/session.py", line 51, in <module>
    from dateutil.tz import tzutc
  File "/Users/alex/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/dateutil/tz/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .tz import *
  File "/Users/alex/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.py", line 19, in <module>
    from six.moves import _thread
ImportError: cannot import name _thread
```

How do I solve that?

Oh and first post on Stack Overflow so I hope I'm asking in the right place.

Edit : forgot to mention I installed everything with `brew`.

Comment: You may want to consider uninstalling and installing Anaconda.  You can create a python2 environment that Jupyter notebook in you base installation can see.  1. install Anaconda.  2. `conda create -n py2 python=2.7`  3. launch Jupyter notebook via `jupyter notebook`  4. The "new" button will have both the 3.6 and 2.7 python kernels available.

Comment: Forgot to mention : installed everything with brew.

Comment: Finally installed Anaconda. Problem solved :-)